# What is ELF : ELF error?

Tags: compiler-errors, x86

I use 64 bit machine, but sometimes when i try to install and run 32 bit applications, i encounter with such kind of errors. Can anybody put some light into it.

Comment: See [Executable and Linkable Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format). The error is most likely your system hasn't been set up properly to execute 32-bit binaries.

Comment: Thanks Joachim Pileborg, the wiki link you provided was informative.